# Reports API : definition of Gmail Customer Usage parameter num_30day_active_users

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I need clarification on the definition of `num_30day_active_users`.

In the doc at [https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/gmail] the note says: "The number of **active user Gmail accounts** in the past 30 days from the date of this report."

My question is: what does "active" mean here? Does it mean active user accounts under the customer who have a license to use Gmail? Or, does it mean users who had actual Gmail activity in the period?

When comparing to other parameters, "active" is used in placed of "accessed," e.g.:

"num_30day_pop_users    integer     The number of users who **accessed POP** in the past 30 days from the date of this report."

vs:

"num_30day_active_users     integer     The number of **active user** Gmail accounts in the past 30 days from the date of this report."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*`num_30day_active_users` specifically means number of users who have had some kind of activity on Gmail in the last 30 days. This could be as minor as simply logging into Gmail.*

*General Google account sign in (for example, YouTube or Drive) does not count,* ***only*** *Gmail.*